# Add inner density to translucent material

Tags: materials, transparency, glass

I'm trying to create this underwater pond scene. Here is the reference:

[image]

As you can see, because the plants are a little translucent, the light shines through and we can see their cores.

How can I achieve this? I don't even know what to call it. Right now my plants don't have any core to it, they look weird.

Appreciate any help, thank you!

[image]

Comment: that render do you use?

Comment: imho you should learn about "subsurface scattering" (aka SSS). It' slike when you set a lamp behinf human ears... you see that light "translucency". See either https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/properties/subsurface_scattering.html or https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/sss.html to get the basics